# MEAN Stack Application having problem in functions.sass file

Tags: sass, mean-stack, node-sass, bulma

I am trying to import and launch a project: MEAN Stack Task Manager Application from this git repository: https://github.com/Devstackr/task-manager-mean-stack

I have successfully launched the application using `ng serve` and it is visible from my web browser at this address: http://localhost:4200/

However, all of the functionalities are not working: I am able to click the '+ List- button, but not actually able to create a list inside the application. Also, the sign-up or login page is not there at the start when I am launching the application.

This is the functions.sass code inside the bulma package:

```
@function mergeColorMaps($bulma-colors, $custom-colors)
  // we return at least bulma hardcoded colors
  $merged-colors: $bulma-colors

  // we want a map as input
  @if type-of($custom-colors) == 'map'
    @each $name, $components in $custom-colors
      // color name should be a string and colors pair a list with at least one element
      @if type-of($name) == 'string' and (type-of($components) == 'list' or type-of($components) == 'color') and length($components) >= 1
        $color-base: null

        // the param can either be a single color
        // or a list of 2 colors
        @if type-of($components) == 'color'
          $color-base: $components
        @else if type-of($components) == 'list'
          $color-base: nth($components, 1)

        $color-invert: null
        // is an inverted color provided in the list
        @if length($components) > 1
          $color-invert: nth($components, 2)

        // we only want a color as base color
        @if type-of($color-base) == 'color'
          // if inverted color is not provided or is not a color we compute it
          @if type-of($color-invert) != 'color'
            $color-invert: findColorInvert($color-base)

          // we merge this colors elements as map with bulma colors (we can override them this way, no multiple definition for the same name)
          $merged-colors: map_merge($merged-colors, ($name: ($color-base, $color-invert)))

  @return $merged-colors

@function powerNumber($number, $exp)
  $value: 1
  @if $exp > 0
    @for $i from 1 through $exp
      $value: $value * $number
  @else if $exp < 0
    @for $i from 1 through -$exp
      $value: $value / $number
  @return $value

@function colorLuminance($color)
  $color-rgb: ('red': red($color),'green': green($color),'blue': blue($color))
  @each $name, $value in $color-rgb
    $adjusted: 0
    $value: $value / 255
    @if $value < 0.03928
      $value: $value / 12.92
    @else
      $value: ($value + .055) / 1.055
      $value: powerNumber($value, 2)
    $color-rgb: map-merge($color-rgb, ($name: $value))
  @return (map-get($color-rgb, 'red') * .2126) + (map-get($color-rgb, 'green') * .7152) + (map-get($color-rgb, 'blue') * .0722)

@function findColorInvert($color)
  @if (colorLuminance($color) > 0.55)
    @return rgba(#000, 0.7)
  @else
    @return #fff
```

These are the error messages I am getting:

```
Recommendation: math.div($value, 255) or calc($value / 255)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
49 │     $value: $value / 255
   │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\functions.sass 49:13          colorLuminance()
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\functions.sass 59:8           findColorInvert()
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\derived-variables.sass 13:17  @import
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\_all.sass 5:9                 @import
    node_modules\bulma\bulma.sass 3:9                               @import
    stdin 4:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
```

```
Recommendation: math.div($value + 0.055, 1.055) or calc(($value + 0.055) / 1.055)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
53 │       $value: ($value + .055) / 1.055
   │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\functions.sass 53:15          colorLuminance()
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\functions.sass 59:8           findColorInvert()
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\derived-variables.sass 13:17  @import
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\_all.sass 5:9                 @import
    node_modules\bulma\bulma.sass 3:9                               @import
    stdin 4:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
```

```
Recommendation: math.div($value, 12.92) or calc($value / 12.92)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
51 │       $value: $value / 12.92
   │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\bulma\sass\utilities\functions.sass 51:15  colorLuminance()
    node_modules\bulma\sass\components\message.sass 43:23   @import
    node_modules\bulma\sass\components\_all.sass 10:9       @import
    node_modules\bulma\bulma.sass 6:9                       @import
    stdin 4:9                                               root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
```

```
Recommendation: math.div($i, 12) or calc($i / 12)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
62 │       width: percentage($i / 12)
   │                         ^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\bulma\sass\grid\columns.sass 62:25  @import
    node_modules\bulma\sass\grid\_all.sass 3:9       @import
    node_modules\bulma\bulma.sass 7:9                @import
    stdin 4:9                                        root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
```

```
Recommendation: math.div($i, 12) or calc($i / 12)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
64 │       margin-left: percentage($i / 12)
   │                               ^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\bulma\sass\grid\columns.sass 64:31  @import
    node_modules\bulma\sass\grid\_all.sass 3:9       @import
    node_modules\bulma\bulma.sass 7:9                @import
    stdin 4:9                                        root stylesheet

Warning: 13 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.
```

I was consulting ChatGPT:
The functions.sass file appears to be a part of the Bulma CSS framework and contains Sass functions that are used to generate colors and their inverses. The deprecation warning is related to the use of / operator for division outside of calc() function.

Although this warning may not necessarily cause the application to malfunction, it is recommended to update the Sass code to eliminate the warning as it could cause issues in the future if left unresolved. You can update the Sass code by modifying the functions.sass file as described in the recommendation provided in the warning message.

Here's an example of how you could modify the colorLuminance() function to eliminate the warning:

```
@function colorLuminance($color)
  $color-rgb: ('red': red($color),'green': green($color),'blue': blue($color))
  @each $name, $value in $color-rgb
    $adjusted: 0
    $value: math.div($value, 255) // update division here
    @if $value < 0.03928
      $value: math.div($value, 12.92) // update division here
    @else
      $value: math.div(($value + .055), 1.055) // update division here
      $value: powerNumber($value, 2)
    $color-rgb: map-merge($color-rgb, ($name: $value))
  @return (map-get($color-rgb, 'red') * .2126) + (map-get($color-rgb, 'green') * .7152) + (map-get($color-rgb, 'blue') * .0722)
```

Even after updating this code snippet, I am getting the same error.